# Prove there is no integer solution to $a^2 - b^2 = 2$ by contradiction

Tags: solution-verification

I have been trying this question for a long time, as a similar one will be in my test next week. I have done this:

$a^2 - b^2 = 2  $
$a^2 = 2 + b^2  $
$a = \sqrt2 + b$

As $\sqrt2$ is not an integer, and if b is an integer, adding them together will yield a non-integer which proves that there is no integer solution.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please learn to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to type the math in your questions.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange. This could be proved considering remainders modulo $4$

Comment: But $\sqrt {2+b^2}\neq \sqrt 2 + b$

Comment: Look at $(a-b)(a+b)=2$.

Comment: The two least possible difference of squares of integers are 1 and 3 , therefore no solutions @YvesDaoust

Answer (score 1):

$a-b$ and $a+b$ have the same parity, hence their product is odd or a multiple of $4$.

Answer (score 0):

The two least difference of squares of integers are 1 and 3 , all the other difference of squares are greater than these ,

Therefore , no integer solutions

Comment: You're correct (besides $0$), but can you prove it?

Answer (score 0):

Can restrict to $a, b \ge 0$, since the expression is quadratic.

$(a-b) (a+b) =2;$

$2$ is a prime number, hence either

1)$a-b=1$, and $a+b=2$ or

2)$a-b=2$, and $a+b=1;$

No integer solutions for the above equations.